# x and y must have same first dimension ERROR in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying to plot the FFT of a sinewave with different frequencies. I got my sinewave plot but finding it difficult to plot the FFT of the signal.

```
A = 2.0                     
fs = 5000                   
nsample = 200 
T=1.0/fs      
ff = np.array([200, 600, 1000]) # different freq under test

#Generating the test sinusoidals
x = np.arange(0,nsample)

normalisedFreq = 2*np.pi*ff/fs

# create the three sinusoids and generating waveform 
y = np.zeros(nsample)

for w in normalisedFreq :
   y=y+A*np.sin(w*x)

# generating Fast Fourier Transform
n_fft=len(y)

magnitude = 2*np.abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(y,n_fft))/n_fft

cutoff = m.ceil((n_fft+1)/2)             #nyquist frequency 

freq=np.array((0,cutoff-1)*(fs/n_fft))   #frequency vector

plt.subplot (211)
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(freq,magnitude)

plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

This error occurs when I try to plot the Freq and magnitude.

Help please, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix it, but it seems that the error says the length of the freq and length of the magnitude are different.

I think you either need to create freq with the same length as magnitude or truncate magnitude array to match freq

Compring `len(magnitude)` and `len(freg)` might be a reasonable first step to debug the issue.